# Windows - Programatically check if hosted wlan network is possible on system's hardware

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wifi

I am looking for a way to check if WLAN hostednetwork (aka setting up the AP instead of connecting to network) funcionality is avaialable on system.

Currently I am invoking `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` command to set it up, but the output of that command is too unexpected to really check it programatically (depends on windows locale and so on). Plus, I'd like to have the information *before* calling this command.

I thought that maybe `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow` would give non-zero exit status if there are no WLAN devices on system or hostednetwork mode is not supported by hardware, but it seems to return zero always (given correct syntax).

The program I need to implement it in is written in C#, so any .NET or P/Invoke solution should be fine.

I am also using [ManagedWifi API](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) to some extent, but couldn't find the solution to my question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read back from the process's output stream. 
When you setup you're process it probably looks something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Then to check if hosted network is supported pass the command:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan show drivers");
process.StandardInput.Close();
```

Make sure you close the input, otherwise the program would hang

Now, if this was a command prompt you'd probably have something like this
[image]

Then just read the output

```
            string[] Lines = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
        string LineString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            LineString = Lines[i];
            if (LineString.Contains("Hosted network supported") && LineString.Split(":".ToCharArray())[1].Trim() == "Yes")  return true;
        }
        return false;
```

use this link for more useful commands:
[enter link description here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-WiFi-Hotspot-Using-the-Command-Prompt)